# High CPU Usage OpenGL Ver 3.1 + SDL2

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl, cpu

In my project I use SDL2 + OpenGL Ver 3.1. There is simple code. Function VPreRender() is called when I want to clear buffer and start to draw in it. After that, when I want to show this buffer on the screen, I use functions VPostRender(). These functions are called in the while loop. 
So when I run my program, after 10-20 minutes CPU usage up to 80-95 %. If I do not call these functions, CPU usage is 10-15%. What I do wrong? Why is so high CPU usage ?

```
bool SDLRender::VPreRender()
{
    glClear ( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );
}

bool SDLRender::VPostRender()
{
    SDL_GL_SwapWindow(m_pWindow);
}
```

Comment: How does your loop look like? If you have while(true) { VPreRender(); VPostRender(); } then it's not odd that you get high CPU.

Comment: If that's all you have, then you're not giving the GPU anything to do, so the CPU has nothing to wait on and will repeatedly execute the loop as fast as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You generally want a sleep somewhere deep in there (though ideal is to do it through a condition variable) to prevent the thread from going as fast as it possibly can. Otherwise you'll even get CPU usage to 100% with an empty infinite loop without any sleeps in there on a single-processor machine. This can be bad if you're targeting systems that have limited battery.

Typically GUI systems do this implicitly as part of their event processing. `SDL_WaitEventTimeout`, for example, should do it, and just using that with a timeout value of 1 millisecond in your event processing loop might get your CPU usage down to almost zero when there's nothing to do.

It's generally not recommended to sleep manually and to restructure your event loop instead to allow the system to do it under the hood as appropriate, but you might be able to manually sleep as well using `SDL_Delay`. Sometimes having that manual control is useful in a real-time application like a game where it might be useful to be a control freak, but you have to be careful not to let the event queue pile up.

Comment: One could also set swap interval to one. That would tell driver to throttle application not render more frames than display refresh rate is.